# How to define variable with CSS value from HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, css

How to change value of element.style.fontSize? I have the font HTML element with inline style font-size: 20px; how do i change size of this using JS? Getting this by element.style.fontSize will give "20px" not just 20. So how can I get rid of "px"

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you searched? This is really basic stuff. Please show some effort.

Comment: I have some issues with adding code here.

Comment: If you are using Jquery you can do this `$('#bulwa').css('font-size', '20px');`

Comment: @JanDycz To add code just add a newline and paste the code indented by 4 spaces. Or put inline code in `\`` characters.

Comment: Still can't add this code in any way. Sorry for that. I am not using JQuery. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoqRWJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp), it will remove the `px`

```
var rozmiar = parseInt(divek.style.fontSize);
```